# How to speed up grouping and add to dictionary

Tags: c#, list, linq, dictionary, optimization

I have code:

```
Dictionary<long, List<Data>> daDictTmp = retValTmp
    .Where(w => w.IdData.HasValue)
    .GroupBy(d => d.IdData.Value) 
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.ToList());
```

Is there any other way to do this operation faster?

Comment: Why is it not fast enough? What is the scenario you are dealing with? What is the context in which this operation is taking place?

Comment: Maybe you are doing this too often

Comment: It is not about the frequency of performing an operation. 
RetValTmp contains a huge set of measurements, I amnot claim that this method is slow, but I just do not know another way which can group the data in this way, hence the question is is there any other faster way?

Comment: What do you do with the dictionary after creating it? How do you use it?

Comment: Do you really need `Dictionary`? The way you defined it It's basically a multi dictionary, hence can be replaced with `Lookup`, i.e. instead of `GroupBy(...).ToDictionary(...)` use `ToLookup(...)`

Comment: How many entries are there in `retValTmp`? Can you show us the definition of the `Data` class?

Comment: Something about 1 mln

Comment: @GiladGreen I have to change DateTime to another value, depending on IdData.

Comment: `GroupBy` creates a hash structure for the grouping, followed by `ToDictionary` creating the `Dictionary` isn't very efficient. `ToLookup` creates an internally implemented hash once.